# If File attribute=this do this in batch

Tags: batch-file, attr

I want a batch script to execute specific commands depending on the file attributes of a file. For example:

```
If attrib %windir%\system32\bcrypt.dll RH (
      echo This is read only, and hidden!
) else (
      echo These file attributes don't match what I was looking for!
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you to all who answered! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type `FOR /?` for information on how to get file attributes. For a `FOR` variable, say, `%f`, that is assigned to a file, you can get its attributes using `%~af`. So, to check if it has R and H attributes:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%f in ("%windir%\system32\bcrypt.dll") do (
    set attributes=%%~af
    if "!attributes:h=!" neq "!attributes!" echo File is hidden.
    if "!attributes:r=!" neq "!attributes!" echo File is read-only.
)
```

Caveat: if the file is hidden, you need to name it explicitly in the `for` command. It won't find the file if you use wildcards.

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('attrib "%windir%\system32\bcrypt.dll"') do (
    set "attributes=%%a"
    set "attributes=!attributes:~0,13!"
)

set "HR=%attributes:~4,2%"
if "!HR!" equ "HR" (
    echo attributes matching
) else (
    echo attributes not matching
)
```

H and R are on 5th and 6th position of the attributes. If they are set you need to check them in this order.

Answer (score 2):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for %%a in ("%windir%\system32\bcrypt.dll") do (

        set "RO_AND_H=1"
        ( for /f "tokens=2 delims=r" %%b in ("%%~aa") do break ) || set "RO_AND_H="
        ( for /f "tokens=2 delims=h" %%b in ("%%~aa") do break ) || set "RO_AND_H="

        if defined RO_AND_H (
            echo File is readonly and hidden
        ) else (
            echo File attributes don't match
        )
    )
```

As already pointed, the `~a` modifier of the `for` replaceable parameter returns the file's attributes list, a string with nine dashes where each of them is replaced with a letter to signal the presence of the attribute (more [here](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)).

```
 FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY     d-------- 
 FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY      -r------- 
 FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE       --a------ 
 FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN        ---h----- 
 FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM        ----s---- 
 FILE_ATTRIBUTE_COMPRESSED    -----c--- 
 FILE_ATTRIBUTE_OFFLINE       ------o-- 
 FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY     -------t- 
 FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT --------l
 FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL        ---------
```

For each of the required attributes, the code tokenizes this string using the wanted attribute as delimiter and try to retrieve the second token.

If the attribute is set, the list is split in two and there will be a second token, so the code in the `do` clause of the `for /f` command is executed (`break` is used just to do nothing).

If the attribute is not present the line will not be splitted, there will be no second token, the code in the `do` clause will not be processed and an failure flag will be set, catched by the conditional operator `||` (run next command if the previous failed) to clear a flag variable.